# CakePHP Session Expires - Frequently

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3 and in core.php. I set the following settings

Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');

Configure::write('Session.timeout', '12');

But after logged in, its frequently logged out. I am not using auth component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session.timeout - Base session timeout in seconds.
use

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', 12 * 60 );
```