# Session expires frequently in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, session-timeout

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6.

I think this question is possibly a duplicate question of these questions :

[CakePHP Session Expires - Frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899383/cakephp-session-expires-frequently)

[cakePHP Session expiring too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331379/cakephp-session-expiring-too-soon)

But, unfortunately, I am not getting any result from these questions' suggestion, which is to increase `Session.timeout`.

I have 2 controllers in my project, for 2 panels: Users & Admin. Both of the panels are getting logged out after a certain time, may be 30 minutes. But, I am not using `Security Component` or `Auth Component` here. My configuration is :

In my `core.php` file :

```
Configure::write('Session',array('defaults'=>'php','timeout'=>4320,'cookieTimeout'=>4320/*,'checkAgent'=>false*/,'autoRegenerate'=>true));
Configure::write('Session.save','cake');
```

Still its not working. What is my fault here ? What should I do ? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `Config/core.php`.

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '180'); // (180 = minutes)
```

Comment: I already tried using "4320", but not working. I think, its actually seconds, not minutes, but not sure yet. @Dave

Comment: Did you try it as a string, not an array?  And it is minutes, as described in the CakePHP book:  "Session.timeout - The **number of minutes** before CakePHP’s session handler expires the session..."

Comment: You mean, I should try using it as a string ? Well, ok, I am trying, but I don't understand how it can be a string ? @Dave

Comment: `'Session.timeout'` is a string (notice the quotes)  `array('defaults'=>'php','timeout'=>4320,'...` is an array (notice the "array(..."

Comment: Nope, still not working. I thought it'd work, but I have been checking this for last couple of days and same result.@Dave

Comment: Will it let you uncheck this as the answer?  If not, maybe I need to edit it to allow that?

Comment: Ok, please edit it, I won't uncheck it. Actually, I think we are very close to it, we just need to get the right thing. @Dave

Comment: @user3808903 - the point of editing it is so you CAN un-check it. People won't come here to help you if they think it's already answered.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't get it :) .Ok, I unchecked it.@Dave